# Type 'ReactType' is not generic (material-ui@next)

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, reactjs, material-ui

i install material ui@next and i have this error in node modules.

`ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/Avatar/Avatar.d.ts:8:15
11:31:52 web.1   |      TS2315: Type 'ReactType' is not generic.
11:31:52 web.1   |  ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/Button/Button.d.ts:7:15
11:31:52 web.1   |      TS2315: Type 'ReactType' is not generic.
11:31:52 web.1   |  ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.d.ts:10:15
11:31:52 web.1   |  webpack: Failed to compile.`

Answer (score 3):

Do an `npm update @types/react`.
In the latest version ReactType is generic

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. To be a bit more specific since I banged my head on the desk for about 40 minutes trying to solve this, here are the packages that I updated: `@types/react`, `@types/react-dom`, `react`, and `react-dom` set at version `16.0.34`, `@types/react-router-dom` and `react-router-dom` set at `4.2.2`, and `@types/react-router` set to `4.2.0` in `package.json`. I then cleared `node_modules` and reinstalled, and ran `npm upgrade` for good measure. It worked, although probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by deleting my `node_modules` folder and my `yarn.lock` file and then reinstalling modules with `yarn` (or `npm i`).

After reinstalling I had a newer version of react and @types/react, which fixes this issue.