# Material-ui-next typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, react-redux, material-ui

I created a default VS2017 react-redux template and tried to add material-ui-next component and I am getting following error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigationButton.d.ts:6:74 TS2344: Type '"onChange"' does not satisfy the constraint '"className" | "style" | "component" | "classes" | "innerRef" | "centerRipple" | "disableRipple" |...'. 
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.d.ts:6:13 TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AnchorHTMLAttributes'. 
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/Snackbar/Snackbar.d.ts:10:18 TS2430: Interface 'SnackbarProps' incorrectly extends interface 'Pick<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & Partial<TransitionHandlers> & { classes: any; }, "defaultCh...'. Type 'SnackbarProps' is not assignable to type 'Pick<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & Partial<TransitionHandlers> & { classes: any; }, "defaultCh...'. Types of property 'action' are incompatible. Type 'ReactElement<any> | ReactElement<any>[]' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'ReactElement<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This is my code:

```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as PetGiftboxProbabilitiesState from 
'../store/PetGiftboxProbabilities';
import { GridList, GridListTile } from 'material-ui/GridList';

// At runtime, Redux will merge together...
type PetGiftboxProbabilityProps =
PetGiftboxProbabilitiesState.PetGiftboxProbabilitiesState
& typeof PetGiftboxProbabilitiesState.actionCreators    
& RouteComponentProps<{}>;

class FetchData extends React.Component<PetGiftboxProbabilityProps, {}> {
componentWillMount() {
    // This method runs when the component is first added to the page
    this.props.requestPetGiftboxProbabilities();
}
public render() {
    return <div>
        <h1>Pet giftbox forecast</h1>
        {this.renderForecastsTable()}
    </div>;
}
private renderForecastsTable() {
    return <GridList cellHeight={160}>
        {this.props.petGiftboxProbabilities.map(pet =>
            <GridListTile key={pet.petId}>
                <img className="pet-image" src={pet.imageUrl} alt=
 {pet.petName} />
            </GridListTile>
        )}
    </GridList>;
 }
}

export default connect(
(state: ApplicationState) => state.PetGiftboxProbabilities,
PetGiftboxProbabilitiesState.actionCreators          
)(FetchData as any) as typeof FetchData;
```

What is wrong with my code?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 6/2/2018:
I wouldn't recommend pinning to these old versions anymore. The latest versions of React types and material-ui should work together, although as of today there's a different typing issue with a fix pending that has a simple workaround: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11656

My current setup (next version of `@material-ui/core` should fix the issue caused by TS 2.9):

```
"@material-ui/core": "^1.1.0",
"@types/react": "^16.3.16",
"typescript": "^2.9.1"
```

---

I just had the same issue. An answer over in [Type 'ReactType' is not generic (material-ui@next)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148533/type-reacttype-is-not-generic-material-uinext) pointed me in the right direction, but here are the specific packages and versions that I needed to update to:

```
"@types/react": "16.0.34",
"@types/react-dom": "16.0.34",
"@types/react-router": "4.2.0",
"@types/react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
"react": "16.0.34",
"react-dom": "16.0.34",
"react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
```

You could try updating those in `package.json` manually then running `npm upgrade`, or dropping `node_modules` and reinstalling. It ended up working for me, although it was a roundabout path of installing/upgrading/head banging for about 40 minutes before it finally compiled. I also recommend checking `node_modules/@types/react/package.json` to see which version is actually being used, if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`npm upgrade` worked for me - I started with yarn but quickly switched over when I moved to `Material-UI-next`.